# typo3 powermail 2.0.1 backend mail list - extended search, extended export settings, excel and csv symbols don't work

Tags: search, export, typo3, backend

If I click to open the extended search or extended export settings for the mail list, it doesn't work, they are still hidden! The same for export symbols like excel and csv, they don't work, nothing happens! Does somebody know how to resolve this problem! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

How much mail do you have?

I experienced something similar and it was because we had too many mails saved. Due to the quantity of mail it needed to get, the connection timed out.

Try limiting the quantity of mail you wish to export.

Take note that we use an older version of powermail. It may not apply to 2.0.1.